# Microsoft Sync Framework COM Exception For Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am working on a Windows Application for sync. So as part of it, I have tried the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617386.aspx

I have created a C# Console Application to try the sync framework . I get an error like this

```
"Exception from File Sync Provider:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM cla
ss factory for component with CLSID {031913FE-EB2A-49F2-B2BE-B996B2448CD4} faile
d due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRES
ULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."
```

Can you please tell me what should I do to rectify this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Framework in managed code works via COM interop, so this exception occurs when one of the underlying COM components isn't registered correctly. I don't remember if the error is the same, but it can also occur if the 32-bit framework has been installed, but you're running a 64-bit app, or vice versa.

I'd try downloading the 2.1 redistributable package (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502) and installing the relevant packages and see if that helps. Specifically, I think you want Synchronization-v2.1-x86-ENU.msi and Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried changing the bit of my application and now it works fine .